# Javascript Promise Chaining Issues (Ember)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I'm trying to upload a file to a remote server, get the path for that file on that server, and then save it in a record to my own API. Over half the time, the code crashes because returnedNewFile is undefined (though I've checked console.log(newFile) in the previous .then() function and it's always a promise object. What could be causing this behavior? What could be causing returnedNewFile to sometimes be null/undefined? I'm using Django REST + django-rest-json-api + ember.js 2.6, and this code is in a component's javascript file. Thank you in advance!

```
  store.findRecord('file', folderid).then(function(folder) {
    var file = fileList.pop();
    var newFile = fm.uploadFile(folder, file.name, file);
    return newFile;

  }).then(function(returnedNewFile) {
    var name = returnedNewFile.get('name');
    var path = returnedNewFile.get('path');
    var doc = store.createRecord('document', {
      name: name,
      path: path,
    });
    console.log("doc: ", doc);
    doc.save();
    return doc;

  }).then(function(doc) {
    console.log("hi number three");
    var grant = store.createRecord('grant', {
      department: department,
      number: number,
      document: doc,

    });
    grant.save();
    return grant;

  }).then(null, function(error) {
    console.log("Oops: " + error.message)
  });
```

EDIT: Here's the code for `uploadFile()` (waterbutler is the name of the file server being used on the external server ([link](https://github.com/CenterForOpenScience/waterbutler))):

```
uploadFile(folder, name, contents, options = {}) {
    let url = folder.get('links').upload;
    options.data = contents;
    if (!options.query) {
        options.query = {};
    }
    options.query.name = name;
    options.query.kind = 'file';

    let p = this._waterbutlerRequest('PUT', url, options);
    return p.then(() => this._getNewFileInfo(folder, name));
}
```

And here's the code for _getNewFileInfo:

```
/**
 * Get the `file` model for a newly created file.
 *
 * @method _getNewFileInfo
 * @private
 * @param {file} parentFolder Model for the new file's parent folder.
 * @param {String} name Name of the new file.
 * @return {Promise} Promise that resolves to the new file's model or
 * rejects with an error message.
 */
_getNewFileInfo(parentFolder, name) {
    let p = this._reloadModel(parentFolder.get('files'));
    return p.then((files) => files.findBy('name', name));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `fm.uploadFile()` be asynchronous?  What node.js module does that come from so we can look at the doc?

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/CenterForOpenScience/ember-osf/blob/develop/addon/services/file-manager.js) a link to the file-manager (fm) class. `fm.uploadFile()` is asynchronous, but I was under the impression that this kind of chaining is how you account for that. Sounds like I may be off though.

Comment: It might always be a `Promise` instance, but it might sometimes be a promise that fulfills with `undefined`. Show us what `_getNewFileInfo` does.

Comment: @Bergi it's at the bottom of the file linked in my previous comment, but I've also updated my question to include it! Looks like it still shouldn't be returning undefined.

Comment: @Cameron: I see, now the question is just what `files.findBy`- I couldn't find that anywhere in the linked repo

Comment: @Bergi [Here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findBy) is the findBy function. A little bit of digging into the models revealed that files is just the result of a reverse lookup of all the files inside the specified parent folder, so findBy is being called by an array-like object. Looks like it returns undefined if it can't find what it's looking for, so that clears that up. Sounds like a problem with the file upload then?

Comment: @Cameron: Yes, that's likely, or you're querying the file too early. Looks like you'll need to do some debugging… and also introduce error handling for the file being `undefined` to at least avoid crashes in the meantime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117757/discussion-between-cameron-and-bergi).

Comment: `newFile` is still not assigned with any value hence remains `undefined` when you return it since`fm.uploadFile` is async. So you are sort of doing like `resolve(undefined)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Over half the time, the code crashes because returnedNewFile is
>   undefined (though I've checked console.log(newFile) in the previous
>   .then() function and it's always a promise object. What could be
>   causing this behavior?

Promises will resolve other Promise when calling `.then()`. So while you could return a string from promise 1's function, and you would get that same string in its `.then()` call, the same is not true if you returned another Promise inside its function. It will instead resolve that second promise to a concrete value before giving a `.then` result.

So if you called `newFile.then(function(newFileResult) { ...` then `newFileResult` would be the same as what you're now getting in the above code as the `returnedNewFile` argument. Why this library's promises sometimes come back with an `undefined` value is beyond me.

EDIT: Did not quite understand the comment, so an example. I have a function called `getText(str)` that asynchronously retrieves that string.

```
response1 = getText("abc").then(ignoredStr => {
  return "def";
});

response2 = getText("abc").then(ignoredStr => {
  return getText("def");
});

response1.then(function(str1) {
  // "def"
});

response2.then(function(str2) {
  // "def"
});
```

Under a certain understanding of promises, str2 would be a `Promise` instead of a `string`; but that's not the case. It sees it got back a Promise, not a "value", and waits for that before chaining the `.then()` call. Even if getText("def") came back in 3 seconds, it would wait 3 more seconds for the second call before giving us a `.then()` result.

Comment: By resolve that second promise, do you mean forcibly resolve it immediately, or wait until it resolves naturally? I apologize if this is a silly question. Still trying to figure out the nuances of async.

Comment: @Cameron I added an example, hopefully that helps understand.